# how does facebook push their changes to the live site

Tags: facebook, architecture

From this video https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=778890205865 I understood that Facebook moves their changes to their live site on a daily basis.
Some changes are visible, whereas most of them are not visible to the end user. With a userbase of just over 700 million how do they manage to do it without any glitches.
Can someone throw light on this?
I have read about the Gatekeeper which allows Facebook to run different code to different set of users. Is there any other technology involved?
thanks.

Comment: what are you going to do with this?

Comment: I work for a company which leads the e-commerce space in India. I know what it takes to move the code to production and the amount of effort that goes into it. Just wanted to know what if Facebook uses anything specific or the available 3rd party tools. If not anything, at least it would help me to learn and appreciate the effort that people put in to keep the already popular site up and running without glitches. thanks

Comment: found out that you work for eBay in your about.me page :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, they push code to their internal users first, so that staff are using the 'alpha' code.

It's then pushed to the beta teir (sunday I think) which lets developers test against the beta code and report any issues

The beta tier is then pushed live on Tuesday night to the main website

Comment: Hi Ben Sebborn, If possible can you share those links. thanks for your time :)